# Identical data frames with different digests in R?

Tags: r, hash, dataframe

I have two large data frames, `a` and `b` for which `identical(a,b)` is `TRUE`, as is `all.equal(a,b)`, but `identical(digest(a),digest(b))` is `FALSE`.  What could cause this?

What's more, I tried to dig in deeper, by applying digest to bunches of rows.  Incredibly, at least to me, there is agreement in the digest values on sub-frames all the way to the last row of the data frames.

Here is a sequence of comparisons:

```
> identical(a, b)
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(a, b)
[1] TRUE
> digest(a)
[1] "cac56b06078733b6fb520442e5482684"
> digest(b)
[1] "fdd5ab78ca961982d195f800e3cf60af"
> digest(a[1:nrow(a),])
[1] "e44f906723405756509a6b17b5949d1a"
> digest(b[1:nrow(b),])
[1] "e44f906723405756509a6b17b5949d1a"
```

Every method I can think of indicates these two objects are identical, but their digest values are different.  Is there something else about data frames that can produce such discrepancies?

---

For further details: the objects are about 10M rows x 12 columns.  Here's the output of `str()`:

```
'data.frame':   10056987 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ V1 : num  1 11 21 31 41 61 71 81 91 101 ...
 $ V2 : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V3 : num  2 3 2 3 4 5 2 4 2 4 ...
 $ V4 : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V5 : num  1.8 2.29 1.94 2.81 3.06 ...
 $ V6 : num  0.0653 0.0476 0.0324 0.034 0.0257 ...
 $ V7 : num  0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 ...
 $ V8 : num  0.00653 0.00476 0.00324 0.0034 0.00257 ...
 $ V9 : num  1.8 2.3 1.94 2.81 3.06 ...
 $ V10: num  0.1957 0.7021 0.0604 0.1866 0.9371 ...
 $ V11: num  1704 1554 1409 1059 1003 ...
 $ V12: num  23309 23309 23309 23309 23309 ...

> print(object.size(a), units = "Mb")
920.7 Mb
```

---

Update 1: On a whim, I converted these to matrices.  The digests are the same.

```
> aM = as.matrix(a)
> bM= as.matrix(b)
> identical(aM,bM)
[1] TRUE
> digest(aM)
[1] "c5147d459ba385ca8f30dcd43760fc90"
> digest(bM)
[1] "c5147d459ba385ca8f30dcd43760fc90"
```

I then tried converting back to a data frame, and the digest values are equal (and equal to the previous value for `a`).

```
> aMF = as.data.frame(aM)
> bMF = as.data.frame(bM)
> digest(aMF)
[1] "cac56b06078733b6fb520442e5482684"
> digest(bMF)
[1] "cac56b06078733b6fb520442e5482684"
```

So, `b` looks like the bad boy, and it has a colorful past.  `b` came from a much bigger data frame, say `B`.  I took only the columns of `B` that appeared in `a` and checked to see if they were equal.  Well, they were equal, but had different digests.  I converted the column names (from "InformativeColumnName1" to "V1", etc.), just to avoid any issues that might arise - though `all.equal` and `identical` tend to point out when column names differ.

Since I am working on two different programs and don't have simultaneous access to `a` and `b`, it is easiest for me to use the digest values to check the calculations.  However, something seems to be odd in how I extract columns from a data frame and then apply `digest()` to it.

---

**ANSWER:**
It turns out, to my astonishment (dismay, horror, embarrassment, you name it), `identical` is very forgiving about attributes.  I had assumed that only `all.equal` was forgiving about attributes.

This was discovered via Tommy's suggestion `identical(d1, d2, attrib.as.set=FALSE)`.  Running `attributes(a)` is a bad, bad idea: the deluge of row names took awhile before Ctrl-C could interrupt it.  Here is the output of `names(attributes())`:

```
> names(attributes(a))
[1] "names"     "row.names" "class"    
> names(attributes(b))
[1] "names"     "class"     "row.names"
```

They're in different orders!  Kudos to `digest()` for being straight with me.

**UPDATE**

To aid others with this problem, it seems that simply rearranging the attributes will be adequate to get identical hash values.  Since tinkering with attribute orders is new to me, this may break something, but it works in my case.  Note that it is a little time consuming if the objects are big; I'm not aware of a faster method for doing this.  (I'm also looking to move to using matrices or data tables instead of data frames, and this may be another incentive to avoid data frames.)

```
tmpA0   = attributes(a)
tmpA1   = tmpA0[sort(names(tmpA0))]
a2      = a
attributes(a2) = tmpA1

tmpB0   = attributes(b)
tmpB1   = tmpB0[sort(names(tmpB0))]
b2      = b
attributes(b2) = tmpB1

digest(a2)  # e04e624692d82353479efbd713ec03f6
digest(b2)  # e04e624692d82353479efbd713ec03f6

identical(b,b2, attrib.as.set = FALSE) # FALSE
identical(b,b2, attrib.as.set = TRUE) # TRUE
identical(a2,b2, attrib.as.set = FALSE) # TRUE
```

Comment: I experimented a bit more and it seems that when you subset the columns of a `data.frame` (e.g. `a[,1:3]`), you change the order of the attributes!

Comment: @Tommy: Thanks! I just found the same thing with rows. R is sneaky.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without having the actual data.frames it is of course hard to know, but one difference could be the **order** of the attributes. `identical` ignores that by default, but setting `attrib.as.set=FALSE` can change that:

```
d1 <- structure(1, foo=1, bar=2)
d2 <- structure(1, bar=2, foo=1)

identical(d1, d2) # TRUE
identical(d1, d2, attrib.as.set=FALSE) # FALSE
```

Comment: Whoa, what the heck is that?!  That seems to have solved it.  (Will revise question to show this.)

Answer (score 8):

Our [digest](http://cran.r-project.org/package=digest) package uses the internal R function `serialize()` to get what we feed to the hash-generating functions (md5, sha1, ...).

So I strongly suspect that may have something like an attribute differ.  Until you can construct something reproducible that does not depend on your 1e7 x 12 data set, there is little we can do.

Also, the `digest()` function can output intermediate results and (as of the recent 0.5.1 version) even `raw` vectors.  That may help.
Lastly, you can always contact us (as the package maintainers / authors) off-line which happens to be the recommended way within R land, the popularity of StackOverflow not withstanding.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've not been able to produce even a subset of this or any reproducible example that creates this anomaly.  If I could, I would.  Alas, the margins of SO are too small for my data.  I also suspect that the issue is outside of `digest`: if the conversion to matrices makes everything work (or the selection of sub-frames), then it makes me think that the data is subtly transformed.  In other words, I wonder if `digest` is telling the truth, but `identical` is lying to me.  :)  I'm used to `all.equal` being very forgiving.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the attributes reset if you regenerate a data frame from the one you have, like so :

```
reset.data.frame = data.frame(col1 = prob.data.frame$col1, 
                              col2 = prob.data.frame$col2) # etc.
```

So you just have to reset the attributes using this trick before each hash and it should work