# hash - Identical R Dataframes, different hashes (not an attribute problem)

Tags: r, dataframe, hash

I have two dataframes of ~150 rows of `X` and `Y` where `identical(X, Y)` is `TRUE` but `identical(digest(X), digest(Y))` is `FALSE`. I'm looking into why this is the case.

I did look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585316/identical-data-frames-with-different-digests-in-r) and re-ran what they tested, with similar results, but unlike their problem, the attributes for my dataframes are the same. Testing results:

```
> names(attributes(X))
[1] "names"     "row.names" "class"
> names(attributes(Y))
[1] "names"     "row.names" "class"  

> digest(X)
[1] "07b7ef11ce6eaae01ddd79e4facef581"
> digest(Y)
[1] "09d8abcab0af0a72265a9b690f4eacc3"

> digest(X[1:nrow(X),])
[1] "2f338de9972529bd2bc9c39c3c5762ea"
> digest(Y[1:nrow(Y),])
[1] "2f338de9972529bd2bc9c39c3c5762ea"

> identical(X, Y, attrib.as.set=FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```

I also saved the dataframes as .RDS files, and re-read them in.

```
> X_rds <- read_rds("cache_vars/X.rds")
> Y_rds <- read_rds("cache_vars/Y.rds")
> identical(X_rds , Y_rds )
[2] TRUE
> digest(X_rds)
[2] "07b7ef11ce6eaae01ddd79e4facef581"
> digest(Y_rds )
[2] "09d8abcab0af0a72265a9b690f4eacc3"
> identical(X_rds , Y_rds , attrib.as.set=FALSE)
[2] TRUE
```

And like the other poster, converting to matrices and back to dataframe yielded identical digests, so it's probably some structural problem.

```
> X_Mat <- as.matrix(X_rds)
> Y_Mat <- as.matrix(Y_rds)
> identical(digest(X_Mat), digest(Y_Mat))
[2] TRUE
> X_DF <- as.data.frame(X_Mat)
> Y_DF <- as.data.frame(Y_Mat)
> identical(digest(X_DF ), digest(Y_DF))
[2] TRUE
```

Dataframe X was produced from a parallel-designed loop (but with the %do% flag so no actual parallelism was done) and Y was produced from a sequential loop.

The .RDS files for X and Y can be found at [this link](https://github.com/btsai-dev/R-hashing-debug).

**Update:**
MrFlick has it right. As it turns out, the serialization during parallel's rbind function was also adding the `gp=0x20` flag, similar to what they described occurs when writing to RDS.

Comment: Whats your question again?

Comment: How were they created? FYI, `Xraw <- serialize(X, NULL)` (and `Yraw`) followed by `which(Xraw != Yraw)` (for me) returns 9 bytes that are different. Frankly, that doesn't tell me a lot, since I haven't memorized the methodology of `serialize` nor how to quickly know how those bytes are interpreted in the scope of a `data.frame`. Also odd is that the length of `serialize(X, NULL)` is the same as for `Y`, yet the `.rds` files are not the same size. Interesting. Perhaps you can compare how the two frames were created (but I think I'm out of this internals discussion, too heavy for me :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write to `rds`, the objects are serialized. The serialization contains some information in addition to just the values the vectors contain. Note that if we just compare all the columns, they produce a different digests

```
sapply(seq_along(X_rds), function(i)
  digest::digest(X_rds[[i]])==digest::digest(Y_rds[[i]])
)
```

So the vectors that are being stored in the data.frame are different. We can use the internal `inspect` function to get some of the meta-data for the vectors

```
.Internal(inspect(X_rds[[1]]))
# @135305a00 14 REALSXP g0c7 [REF(4),gp=0x20] (len=150, tl=0) 
# 1.009e+06,1.009e+06,1.009e+06,1.009e+06,1.009e+06,...
.Internal(inspect(Y_rds[[1]]))
# @115dbfc00 14 REALSXP g0c7 [REF(29)] (len=150, tl=0) 
# 1.009e+06,1.009e+06,1.009e+06,1.009e+06,1.009e+06,...
```

So we see they differ in the `[]` parts. I believe the `REF()` number represents the reference count to that object for memory clearing purposes. I do not believe that this number is used in the serialization. But the `X_rds` also has `gp=0x20` set. The "gp" stands for "general purpose" bits/flags. I believe in this case it means the GROWABLE_MASK was set on that object. These values are preserved when the object is serialized which is the default behavior for `digest`. Thus these vectors do not have the exact same serialization due to this flag difference.

Another way to see the difference is to look at the desrialization

```
substring(rawToChar(serialize(X_rds[[1]], connection = NULL, ascii = TRUE)), 1, 45)
# [1] "A\n3\n262657\n197888\n5\nUTF-8\n131086\n150\n1009002\n"
substring(rawToChar(serialize(Y_rds[[1]], connection = NULL, ascii = TRUE)), 1, 45)
# [1] "A\n3\n262657\n197888\n5\nUTF-8\n14\n150\n1009002\n1009"
```

We have a a bit of a header, then we start to see the values being output. There is one value where there is a difference and that's where X has 131086 (0x20000E) and Y has 14 (0xE). Those differences are due to the flags where are [written here in the R source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d29fd8b7f3221aaef97f0980108a230623274442/src/main/serialize.c#L1114).

When you use `identical`, only the values in the data.frame are compared, not the additional metadata.

If you wanted to get around this, you could write your own wrapper around `digest` that avoids the serialization. For example

```
dfdigest <- function(x) {
  charsToRaw <- function(x) unlist(lapply(x, charToRaw))
  bytes <- unlist(c(list(charsToRaw(names(x))), 
                    lapply(x, function(col) {
    if (typeof(col)=="double") writeBin(col, raw())
    else if (typeof(col)=="character") charsToRaw(col)
    else stop(paste("unconfigured data type:", typeof(col)))
  })))
  digest::digest(bytes, serialize = FALSE)
}

dfdigest(X_rds)
# [1] "2488505e3ad1a370d030b539a287b7ca"
dfdigest(Y_rds)
# [1] "2488505e3ad1a370d030b539a287b7ca"
```