# identical(X1, X2) is TRUE, but digest::sha1(X1) != digest::sha1(X2)

Tags: r, feather

I have several large data.table saved to disk in .rds files.  I'm looking for ways to reduce the time required to import data.  I was looking into the [feather](https://cran.r-project.org/package=feather) package.  Part of my pipeline is to check for any changes in the input data set based on `digest::sha1()`.  I have, as shown in the following example, that a data.table, saved as a rds, can be read in and the `digest::sha1()` are equal.  However, the data saved as a `.feather` file, read in, and modified to be the same data.tabel, result in different sha1 hashes.  I'm confused because checking `all.equal` and `indentical` return `TRUE` but the hashes are unique.

Why is this happening?  Is it possible to get the same hash with this type of work flow?  How can I easily check if the data has changed if I can't rely on the hashes?  (Real data is several million rows by several hundred columns).

```r
library(data.table)
library(feather)

# build an example data set
set.seed(42)

original_data_table <-
  data.table(
             x = rnorm(100),
             y = factor(sample(1:3, size = 100, replace = TRUE), levels = 1:3, labels = c("lvl1", "lvl2", "lvl3"))
             , 
             id = paste0("subject_", 1:100)
  )

data.table::setkey(original_data_table, id)

# write data as rds
original_data_table_rds <- tempfile()
original_data_table_feather <- tempfile()
saveRDS(object = original_data_table, file = original_data_table_rds)
feather::write_feather(x = original_data_table, path = original_data_table_feather)

# read in the data objects
from_rds        <- readRDS(original_data_table_rds)
from_rds_setted <- data.table::setDT(readRDS(original_data_table_rds))
from_feather    <- feather::read_feather(original_data_table_feather)

# translate from_feather from tibble to data.table
data.table::setDT(from_feather)
data.table::setkey(from_feather, id)

# check that objects are equall, and even identical, to the original
all.equal(from_rds, original_data_table)         # TRUE
#> [1] TRUE
all.equal(from_rds_setted, original_data_table)  # TRUE
#> [1] TRUE
all.equal(from_feather, original_data_table)     # TRUE
#> [1] TRUE

identical(from_rds, original_data_table)         # FALSE
#> [1] FALSE
identical(from_rds_setted, original_data_table)  # TRUE
#> [1] TRUE
identical(from_feather, original_data_table)     # TRUE
#> [1] TRUE

digest::sha1(original_data_table)
#> [1] "4036943c7692f18fc4be615eb1821c29fa17935a"
digest::sha1(from_rds)
#> [1] "4036943c7692f18fc4be615eb1821c29fa17935a"
digest::sha1(from_rds_setted)
#> [1] "4036943c7692f18fc4be615eb1821c29fa17935a"
digest::sha1(from_feather)
#> [1] "cf8cefcc706cbfe343986aa366d44bf2bf965712"

sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Monterey 12.6
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib 
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
#> 
#> time zone: America/Denver
#> tzcode source: internal
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] feather_0.3.5     data.table_1.14.8
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] digest_0.6.33   utf8_1.2.3      fastmap_1.1.1   xfun_0.39      
#>  [5] magrittr_2.0.3  glue_1.6.2      tibble_3.2.1    knitr_1.43     
#>  [9] pkgconfig_2.0.3 htmltools_0.5.5 rmarkdown_2.23  lifecycle_1.0.3
#> [13] cli_3.6.1       fansi_1.0.4     vctrs_0.6.3     reprex_2.0.2   
#> [17] withr_2.5.0     compiler_4.3.1  tools_4.3.1     hms_1.1.3      
#> [21] pillar_1.9.0    evaluate_0.21   Rcpp_1.0.11     yaml_2.3.7     
#> [25] rlang_1.1.1     fs_1.6.2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the attributes (or the ordering of the attributes).  Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585316/identical-data-frames-with-different-digests-in-r ?  Specifically, the "update" section of the question - reordering the attributes of `from_feather` to match the order in `from_rds`, for example

Comment: Thank you @hobo -  this link was the exact bit of additional information I needed to find the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Hobo for the comment on the question I was able to find the solution.  @Hobo was correct, it had to do with the attributes.  The attributes of `original_data_table` and `from_feather` are, as a set, identical, but are order that the list elements are provided in differ.

By setting `attrib.as.set = FALSE` in the `identical` call we can see there is a difference.  Looking at the names of the attributes between `original_data_table` and `from_feather` we see that the first and third elements are traded positions between the two objects.  By setting the order of the attribute elements of `from_feather` to the same order as `original_data_table`, the `digest::sha1` values are as expected.

```r
digest::sha1(original_data_table)
#> [1] "4036943c7692f18fc4be615eb1821c29fa17935a"
digest::sha1(from_rds)
#> [1] "4036943c7692f18fc4be615eb1821c29fa17935a"
digest::sha1(from_rds_setted)
#> [1] "4036943c7692f18fc4be615eb1821c29fa17935a"
digest::sha1(from_feather)
#> [1] "cf8cefcc706cbfe343986aa366d44bf2bf965712"

identical(from_feather, original_data_table, attrib.as.set = FALSE)
#> [1] FALSE
attributes(original_data_table) |> names()
#> [1] "names"             "row.names"         "class"            
#> [4] ".internal.selfref" "sorted"
attributes(from_feather) |> names()
#> [1] "class"             "row.names"         "names"            
#> [4] ".internal.selfref" "sorted"

attributes(from_feather) <- attributes(from_feather)[c("names", "row.names", "class", ".internal.selfref", "sorted")]
identical(from_feather, original_data_table, attrib.as.set = FALSE)
#> [1] TRUE
digest::sha1(original_data_table)
#> [1] "4036943c7692f18fc4be615eb1821c29fa17935a"
digest::sha1(from_rds)
#> [1] "4036943c7692f18fc4be615eb1821c29fa17935a"
digest::sha1(from_rds_setted)
#> [1] "4036943c7692f18fc4be615eb1821c29fa17935a"
digest::sha1(from_feather)
#> [1] "4036943c7692f18fc4be615eb1821c29fa17935a"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>